# Use Include extension on included object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm working with EF and code first. I created a User object which contains a list of the object Role. Each Role object contains a object of type Form. I want to get all roles of a specific user including the "Form" object.

For better understanding: user 1<->n role 1<-> 1 Form

I tried something like that:

```
DBContext.Users.Include(u => u.Roles.AsQueryable().Include(i=>i.Form)).ToList().Where(r => r.Username.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault<User>();
```

This results in:

The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties. Parameter name: path

```
User user = DBContext.Users.Include(u =>     u.Roles.AsQueryable().Include(i=>i.Form)).ToList().Where(r =>    r.Username.Equals(id)).FirstOrDefault<User>();
List<Role> roles = user.Roles.AsQueryable().Include(r=>r.Form).ToList();
```

This doesn't throw any Exception but the Form object is not included in the Role object.

How can I use include on a included object? Is there a way to include "objects" after a linq expression was completed?
Thanks greetings

[Edit] For a better understanding how my model looks

```
public class User
{
    //some properties
    public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class Role
{
    //some properties
    public virtual Form Form { get; set; }
}
public class Form
{
    //some properties
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do an include in another include. Correct way to include a subpath with linq expression is to use select

```
DBContext.Users.Include(u =>u.Roles.Select(i=>i.Form)).ToList()
```

Comment: If I use the select statment with i.Form the list would return IList<Form>. I need as result all Roles including the object Form of the propertie Form or at least the user object which holds all roles including the form propertie. Without including it, the propertie Form is null.

Comment: Have you really test my snippet? You won't get IList<Form> You will get a IList<User>, in every User object in the list is a IList<Role> and in ever Role object in the second list is one Form member.var users = DBContext.Users.Include(i => i.Roles.Select(s => s.Form)).ToList();
          var form = users.First().Roles.First().Form;

Comment: See also the remarks in the official msdn docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx

_To include a collection and then a reference one level down: query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference))_

Comment: Thanks! I didn't watched carefully and wrote DBContext.Users.Include(u =>u.Roles).Select(i=>i.Form).ToList(). My Fault. Sry and thanks again!